# Dependent selection option field in codeigniter and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter, I just want to ask on how to populate the second select option field depending on the first option field from the database. 
I have two tables the city and province. The first option field is the province if the user chooses on a particular province,  the second option field which is the city will automatically populate.
This is my database.

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `province_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`,`city_name`),
  KEY `province_idx` (`province_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `province` FOREIGN KEY (`province_id`) REFERENCES `province` (`province_id`) 
) 

CREATE TABLE `province` (
  `province_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `provice_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`province_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: just do google you can find many demo's

Comment: first load first drop down, than on change of that drop down populate another dropdown dynamic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654112/how-to-make-a-dependent-dropdown-in-codeigniter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a dependent dropdown in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654112/how-to-make-a-dependent-dropdown-in-codeigniter)